# Cocos2d how to get object position from tile map depending on retina or not?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hey guys I have a object sitting in my tile map for spawn point reference, problem is the -hd version is twice as big as the non -hd version, so going:

(width = width of character getting spawned)
int spawnX = (width/2) + [tilemap spawnX];

Get's the wrong position when in hd mode, because the tile map is in pixels but cocos2d is in points.

I.E I could test if retina display was supported, but from what I hear thats a bit dodgey.

How can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retina display is supported properly on cocos2d v2.0 rc2.

First, make sure to call `[director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES]` in your app launch with all the other cocos2d initialization stuff.

Then, use `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * pointCount` to get pixels out of it.
There are also other convenience macros defined in the same header as the `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()` macro to help you convert `CGRect`s, etc. that are in points to pixels, and vice-versa.